# Was the U.S. Civil War unique regarding its relation to slavery? (people fighting for the freedom of a goup they were not part of)

Tags: american-civil-war, slavery

Although the U.S. Civil War had multiple and complex causes, the question of slavery was a very important factor.

As slavery was part of most civilizations on all continents (especially before the last couple of centuries), and in many cases the slave class had a different ethnic makeup than the privileged class, it occurred to me that I know about many slave revolts from different eras and locations, but all of them involve the slave class fighting against the privileged class.

In the US Civil War the overwhelming majority of the fighters of the anti-slavery side were not members of the slave class. Was this unique in history? I never heard about an army of Ottomans or Mongols or Romans or Almohads etc. to fight for the freedom of the very ethnic groups who served them (or at least people from the same group as them) as slaves.

Members of a privileged group fighting (as in risking their lives in battle, not just making speeches) for the freedom of a group they are not part of. Was this thing unique for the US civil War? If not, was it the first case?

<sub>I wouldn't count a few sympathizers who join a slave revolt despite being of higher social standing. For an example to count, the anti-slavery fight has to be started and led mainly by people who are (or could be if they wanted) members of the slave-owning class.</sub>

Comment: Does this qualify? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Africa_Squadron Also, while the slavery was the issue that divided the USA, the formal cause was the secession of US states (in you saw the film Lincoln, it states that had not the 14th ammendment passed, slavery would have still been legal in the South after the war).

Comment: This is an opinion question. I've been a part of too many discussions of this topic that degenerate into arguments and beyond.  Each participant in the war will have come to that position through an unique mixture of influences.  I also believe American chattel slavery is quite distinct from slavery practiced anywhere else on the planet.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace : Both the title and the text contain the word "slavery", so it should be obvious that it's about slavery as an institution, the question even explains what type of slavery I was referring to, and that I refer to slavery literally (people treated as property) and not figuratively. But if you still feel that it's not clear enough, I'm open to suggestions how to improve the answer to make it more obvious. There are many questions about slavery on this site, many of them high-voted, and seemingly all of them use the word literally, not figuratively.

Comment: @vsz and yet, Oldcat's answer....

Comment: Many colonial endeavours were ostensibly about ending slavery (or some other practice deemed unacceptable). I am guessing that it's not what you are looking for however.

Comment: Was it about slavery, or about preserving the Union? I thought Lincoln stated he would preserve the Union **with** slavery, if that's what it took?

Comment: @TheHonRose : This is why I wrote the first paragraph. Even if slavery was not the main (or the only) trigger, ending slavery became, as far as I know, an important rallying point for the North.

Comment: Would you count the liberation of France from Nazi Germany as "people fighting for the freedom of a group they were not a part of?"

Comment: @Αδριανός : were people in Nazi Germany used as slaves in the classical sense, bought and sold, openly by the general population? Please read the whole title, and the question itself, not just part of the title. If we only took the last part of the title out of context, then every single war where a power helped one side of a civil war in a different country would count.

Comment: @vsz In fact I did read the whole question-- And nowhere in the question do you specify "slavery in the classical sense." But at any rate, Nazi Germany is in fact a very good example of a totalitarian state which employed slave labor to the benefit of, if not the direct employ, of the general population. Many business conglomerates, across the nation, employed knowingly forced Jewish labor. These were not, necessarily, government owned businesses. And in fact, Allied forces did know about the holocaust, as early as 1942 (continued).

Comment: @vsz (continued from prior comment) Allied forces, just like Union forces, were not explicitly fighting for the liberation of the enslaved population the enemy held. In both cases, there were ulterior political motivations, whether, preserving the Union, or fighting to curb the rise of fascism. The final result was the restoration of civil liberties to an *enslaved* minority. There are definite similarities in both systems. Although I concede that the Nazi slave system was less entrenched in normal society than that of the South, it nonetheless did existed to serve the general population.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how narrowly you define 'freedom'. Certainly many nations have fought to remove districts and states from other nation's rule.  For example, the French intervention in the American Revolution helped the Colonists be "free" in their minds, even though they were not chattel slaves originally.

Comment: And the Spanish Civil War drew many non-Spaniards to fight Fascism.